# How to display only a certain part of the content in a Panel?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I have a `Panel` of size {850, 400} as `myPanel` with a `Pane` of size {450, 400} and four images assigned to `forwardPicture`, `backwardPicture`, `picture1` and `picture2`.

```
forwardPicture=
```

[image]

```
backwardPicture=
```

[image]

```
picture1=
```

[image]

```
picture2=
```

[image]

Both `picture1` and `picture2` are of size {400, 400},

```
myPanel = Panel[Row[{picture1, picture2}], ImageSize -> {850, 400}];

Row[{
  MouseAppearance[EventHandler[
    Framed[backwardPicture, 
     FrameStyle -> None], {"MouseClicked" :> ""}], "LinkHand"],
  Pane[myPanel, ImageSize -> {450, 400}, Scrollbars -> None], 
  MouseAppearance[EventHandler[
    Framed[forwardPicture, 
     FrameStyle -> None], {"MouseClicked" :> ""}], "LinkHand"]
  }]
```

After evaluation, I get this:

[image]

I want to move the images from right to left within the `Pane` whenever `forwardPicture` is pressed, and move them from left to right whenever `backwardPicture` is pressed. I don't want any scrollbars in the `Pane`. I don't want to move the images at one click: I want to move them a little bit for every click, until the full image is displayed. Can anybody help me?

Comment: István Zachar,we have to solve this problem very easily,If we have to fix the dimensions to the `panel`.                   why because,at the starting time `Panel` displayed with some certain dimensions(min:0,max:50),and then next dimensions increased like (min:10,max=60) whenever `forwardPicture` is pressed...I think like that ,so I mentioned "dimension".

Comment: Ok, in the meantime I've figured it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the `ScrollPosition` option in `Pane`, even though there are no scroll bars. Set this to a `Dynamic` value and make the `"MouseClicked"` action increase or decrease that value.

e.g.

```
DynamicModule[{s},
  Row[{
  MouseAppearance[EventHandler[Framed[backwardPicture, FrameStyle -> None],
    {"MouseClicked" :> (s -= 10)}], "LinkHand"], 
  Pane[myPanel, ImageSize -> {450, 400}, Scrollbars -> None, ScrollPosition -> Dynamic[{s, 0}]], 
  MouseAppearance[EventHandler[Framed[forwardPicture, FrameStyle -> None],
    {"MouseClicked" :> (s += 10)}], "LinkHand"]}]]
```

Comment: Simon Woods, Thanks for your reply...but moving `Appearance`was bad..so How can I change that?

Comment: @subbu, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: `ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable"` might be an alternative -- in which case the forward and back arrows are probably redundant.

Comment: @Simon Woods,we have to see this type of application,whenever we have to open new tab in google chrome,                           in that moving `Appearance` was so good,whenever we have to press on `forwardButton` and `Backwardbutton`...can we provide `Appearance` like that?

Comment: @subbu, I don't use google chrome. Can you *describe* what makes the appearance good?

Answer (score 3):

I've used `ImageAssemble` to replace `Row` in `myPanel`, as `Row` is subject to linebreaks. The left/right step buttons use a +/-20 unit stepsize, this can be customized for the user's taste.

```
DynamicModule[{myPanel, max, d = 0},
 myPanel = 
  ImageAssemble@{ImageResize[picture1, {Automatic, 400}], 
    ImageResize[picture2, {Automatic, 400}]};
 max = First@ImageDimensions@myPanel;
 Panel@Row[{
    MouseAppearance[EventHandler[Framed[backwardPicture, 
       FrameStyle -> None], {"MouseClicked" :> (d = Min[d + 20, max - 450])}], 
     "LinkHand"],
    Pane[Show[myPanel, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 400}], 
     Scrollbars -> False, ImageSize -> {450, 400}, 
     ScrollPosition -> Dynamic@{d, 0}],
    MouseAppearance[EventHandler[
      Framed[forwardPicture, FrameStyle -> None], {"MouseClicked" :> (d = Max[0, d - 20])}],
      "LinkHand"]
    }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]